# Is it possible to measure pwm load current using opamp based high side current sensing?

Tags: adc, pwm, current-measurement, high-voltage, duty-cycle

I am referring this [app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu849/tidu849.pdf?ts=1593657867369&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FTIDA-00528), hope to use as unidirectional current sensing for a PWM load

PWM load - load is a resistor,

PWM signal - 100Hz, 150V.

Load current 18mA

Duty 5% (PWM resolution 8 bit)

Duty cycle on time 0.58ms

Duty cycle off time 9.41ms

[OPA333](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa333.pdf?ts=1593746305141&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FOPA333%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dasc-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DOPA333%2526ds_k%253DOPA333%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCjwKCAjwi_b3BRAGEiwAemPNU8cvxz9PJ3Ze1MW9cCiO6BKgT-aNcgrbMK8PTccTJTMlHqZXYf6zbhoCOqwQAvD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) has gain bandwidth 350kHz which is more than enough to capture 100Hz

**I have following doubts,**

Is the reference design will work for my application spec? (I will use R sense = 5.55Ohm)

Is ADC sampling rate 250Hz enough to capture current from PWM pulses? (250Hz > 2x PWM signal frequency)

- I need to capture all PWM pulses when ADC is being read,i can use higher ADC sampling rates eg- 800 samples per second or 800Hz

I need to measure current for short periods- means PWM load is only on for 0.25 sec or 0.75 sec, within those periods I need to measure current to the load.

Comment: It won't work unidirectionally. It will only work for a positive DC voltage and not bidirectional PWM.